# Is it bad to have two webapps each on different servlet container than both on same, on a production server?

Tags: ubuntu, performance, tomcat, jetty

I need to run two webapps on a ubuntu VPS but one(my own webapp) prefers to run in Tomcat & other(Solr webservice) is preferable in Jetty. But I think running a separate server for each webapp would be consuming more resources (like memory consumption would be higher) than both the webapps running on same server, isn't it ?

What may be the other bad if I run both Tomcat & Jetty on a single machine for production use?

Answer (score 3):

No problems technically speaking.

Just run both on different ports, and be mindful of the memory / CPU usage of each.

It would be easy for one badly behaving server to use too many resources and starve the other.